# Event for Sales Order Quote Item

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, sales, sales-quote

Question is about Magento 1.8

While creating order in the admin panel -> Sales -> Orders -> Create New Order

When I add products, I can change the price to "Custom Price" and Update Items as below;

[image]

**What I want**

... What I want is to hook the event when we click "Update Items and Qty" to modify the price by some percentage.

**What I have tried**

I created a simple extension for observer for `sales_quote_save_before` but it's not firing the event, full config is below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyTest_Quote>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyTest_Quote>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <models>
            <MyTest_Quote>
                <class>MyTest_Quote_Model_Observer</class>
            </MyTest_Quote>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_quote_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <MyTest_Quote_price_observer>
                        <class>MyTest_Quote_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>__set_quote_price</method>
                    </MyTest_Quote_price_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_save_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

I may not be using the correct hook? Can you please help me with this, I want to interpret the the custom price added to modify it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event exists, but this seems wrong ...

```
<adminhtml>
    <models>
        <MyTest_Quote>
            <class>MyTest_Quote_Model_Observer</class>
        </MyTest_Quote>
    </models>
    ...
```

Please try

```
<global>
    <models>
        <MyTest_Quote>
            <class>MyTest_Quote_Model</class>
        </MyTest_Quote>
    </models>
</global>
```

In your Observer you can access quote data via `$observer->getQuote()->getData()`.

**Edit:** full class name also works, but i prefer  `<class>MyTest_Quote/observer</class>` for observer section.